# Exporting several scraped tables into a single CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, export-to-csv, scrape

How can I concatenate the tables read from several HTML? I understand they are considered lists and lists are not possible to concatenate, but then how can I insert more than one table scraped from a different URL into one single CSV? Any ideas? Is it possible to save the print output in a variable and then move it into a CSV?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('URL')
df1 = pd.read_html('URL')

print(df, df1)

(**df,df1**).to_csv('name.csv')
```

---

The attribute (**df,df1**) is of course incorrect, just wrote it to describe what I am missing.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Remember [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) returns a list of data frames even if there is only one table on webpage.

Answer (score 0):

pd.read_html returns a list of dataframes. So, in case you are sure that the lists contains dataframes formated in a way that can be concatenated you can consolidate then into a single dataframe, then export it to csv:

```
import pandas as pd

dframes_list1 = pd.read_html('URL1')
dframes_list2 = pd.read_html('URL2')
dframes_all = dframes_list1 + dframes_list2
consolidated_dframe = pd.concat(dframes_all)
consolidated_dframe.to_csv('name.csv')
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you!